# Unable to delete a field

Tags: 8

I'm running this code using `drupal src deletefield.php`

deletefield.php

```
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('article', 'field_govt_dept_')->delete();

// Deleting field.
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('article', 'bundle', 'field_govt_dept_')->delete();
```

But it's coming out with error:

```
@tsmdc:/var/www/html/govtschemes.in$ drush scr deletefield.php
Error: Call to a member function delete() on null in include() (line 5 of /var/www/html/govtschemes.in/deletefield.php) #0                        [error]
phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1162): include()
#1 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_php_script('deletefield.php')
#2 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#3 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('deletefield.php')
#4 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#5 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#6 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/startup.inc(462): drush_main()
#7 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/startup.inc(369): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#8 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#9 /home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar(10): require('phar:///home/ra...')
#10 {main}.
Error: Call to a member function delete() on null in /var/www/html/govtschemes.in/deletefield.php on line 5 #0 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1162): include()
#1 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_php_script('deletefield.php')
#2 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#3 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('deletefield.php')
#4 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#5 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#6 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/startup.inc(462): drush_main()
#7 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/includes/startup.inc(369): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#8 phar:///home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#9 /home/raggupta/bin/drush8.1.16.phar(10): require('phar:///home/ra...')
#10 {main}
Error: Call to a member function delete() on null in include() (line 5 of /var/www/html/govtschemes.in/deletefield.php).
```

**What is the problem?**

Comment: There is no such field.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('article', 'bundle', 'field_govt_dept_')
```

Is returning NULL.

You likely want:

```
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('node', 'article', 'field_govt_dept_')
```

Also, check that the field name `field_govt_dept_` is correct. Does it really end in a trailing underscore? (that can happen, but it's not common).

Comment: `\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('article', 'field_govt_dept_')->delete();` never worked. I just executed your line. Now it works fine. Yes `field_govt_dept_` is correct. I recreated this field without error

Comment: first u pl. tell if I need to execute this line as well, otherwise who knows if error will come in future:  `\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('article', 'field_govt_dept_')->delete();`

Comment: No you don't need it.

Comment: now manual delete of taxonomy isn't working from admin panel. Drupal corrupted @#$!

Comment: This code would not do that.